# How to create a form with many circles so that I could change the background-color of any circle?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is what I want:

[image]

```css
.square{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid gray;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
  <script>
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
          document.write("<div class='square'></div>");
      }
      document.write("<div style='clear:both'></div>");
  }
  </script>
```

I try to change color, but that's not in position that I want.

Comment: Java != JavaScript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another class with desired style and add that class to the circles you want

```js
var emptyRow = 2
var emptyCol = 2

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      if (i < emptyRow && j < emptyCol) {
        document.write("<div class='empty-square'></div>");
      } else {
        document.write("<div class='square'></div>");
      }
    }
    document.write("<div style='clear:both'></div>");
}
```

```css
.square{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid gray;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }
 
 .empty-square{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid gray;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

Comment: what if i want  empty-square with % like 98% mean (i == 0 && [0,1].includes(j)) and 97% mean (i == 0 && [0,1,2].includes(j))

Comment: You can actually just use the row,col number for empty-squares. See the updated code. You can put the values you want in the `emptyRow` and `emptyCol`. Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You Can do this with CSS check this code I give you some example how you can do this

```css
.square{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid gray;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* if you want to change 5th circle */
.square:nth-child(5){  /* Here you want to add nth-child(5) */
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* if you want to change 8th circle */
.square:nth-child(8){ /* Here you want to add nth-child(8) */
  border:1px solid green;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Heare I have 10 Div with class Name SQUARE -->
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```